# How to generate code after app initialization (JHipster)?

Tags: jhipster

I am a jhipster newbie and am trying out different things. Now I have created an app and changed a lot of things already. Everything is running fine. Unfortunately, I noticed only afterwards that I would like to have gatling tests. I did not select gatling during the initial app generation. But is there a way to generate tests like Gatling or Protractor afterwards? What is the intended procedure in terms of best practices?

With entities it is clearly regulated you can add new ones or re-import a .jdl file. Also I know how to add new languages with `jhipster languages`. But what about other frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `.yo-rc.json` file, add "gatling" to `testFrameworks` property like below:

```
 "testFrameworks": ["gatling", "protractor"],
```

Then re-generate your project using `jhipster --with-entities`, using `git diff` to keep only the changes you want